# Unable to change ColorPalette property on Telerik Report graph

Tags: wpf, telerik-reporting

I'm using the Telerik Reports graph wizard to create a bar chart.  Even though I can change the ColorPalette property to GradientPalette and can choose the desired colors, the results are the same flat single color.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for your help and advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Graph's [Color Palette](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/p-telerik-reporting-graph-colorpalette) applies gradient coloring on the whole series, not on each of the the data points. I believe you're trying to achieve gradient-colored bars, but this feature is not supported. If in your bar chart you define series groups, then the first bar will be colored using the palette's BeginColor, the last bar will be colored with the palette's EndColor all the bars between them will have solid color, calculated based on their count and offset from the BeginColor towards the EndColor.

The Gradient Palette makes much sense when used in the Choropleth, where the color represents an additional data measure - see a demo [here](https://demos.telerik.com/reporting/population-density?&skinName=default).